# QGIS PostgreSQL Amazon RDS AWS - id issue

Tags: qgis, postgresql, amazon-web-services

This is a novice question. I created a database using Amazon RDS AWS. Then I connected it to my PostgreSQL.

I am planning to utilize this for multi-user access to digitize blighted areas through QGIS.

in QGIS, there is an option to  CONVERT TO OFFLINE PROJECT. I used a geopackage for that. While I was exploring this in QGIS, I encountered a problem when I merged two selected features and tried to SYNCHRONIZE it. This outright rejected the merged features when I tried to synchronize the offline database.

This has something to do with the ID of my PostgreSQL

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This procedure description doesn't make sense. You created an RDS instance and connected your database to it? How? Then you copied it offline, so you now have three databases?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a novice on this. I created a PostGres database in  RDS, then I used PgAdmin to create a schema. I used QGIS to access that.

I did not copy it to make it offline. there is an option in QGIS to make it offline via Database > Convert to Offline Project.

I only have 1 databse